# Get colors in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, suse

I am connecting to a remote suse 10.0 machine, and I do not get colors on the terminal, while I get them when I connect to a remote Ubuntu machine.

How can I do to get colors on the suse terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on a couple of factors. What is the `TERM` set to when you login to the remote machine

```
ubuntu$ echo $TERM
```

If the terminal type is not set to a terminal capable of colour (i.e. dumb or vt100), then that would be your problem.

Otherwise I suspect you mean that Linux commands are not executing in colour mode by default. Try

```
ubuntu$ ls --color
```

Which you can fix by setting an alias in the user's shell start-up files. (E.g. .bashrc / .bash_profile for bash).

(*And yes I spell colour with a 'u'*).

Answer (score 0):

I'm very newbie on Linux but I know that I get colors when I log in as ROOT but no colors when I log in as me.

How are you loging in?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this:

```
export TERM="linux"
```